# Cosecant and Cotangent Lines on a Function

Tags: functions

In elementary Calculus, when the concept of derivative is being taught, the secant line and the tangent line are demonstrated for better visualization on a function. I was wondering if we can draw other lines, such as cosecant line, cotangent line and the like. If possible, please include some visualization and explanation on how one can describe them.